# python - multi line stdout refresh issue

Tags: python

I have a stats app written in python that on a timer refreshes the ssh screen with stats. Right now it uses os.system('clear') to clear the screen and then outputs a multi line data with the stats.

I'd like to do just do a \r instead of executing the clear but that only works with one line, is it possible to do this with multiple lines?

A classic example of what I want to do is when you execute the "top" command which lists the current processes it updates the screen without executing the "clear" and it's got many lines.

Anyone have any tips for this?

Comment: Could you please clarify: do you want to (1) clear and display only 1 page worth of stats that have changed or (2) clear and display only the first 1 page worth of stats that your program outputs?

Comment: option 1 would be great if that's possible, option 2 would work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really answer your question, but there isn't really anything wrong with calling os.system to clear out the terminal (other than the system running on different operating systems) in which case you could use:

`os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear')`

Comment: The appropriate function in the subprocess module should be used instead of os.system.

Answer (score 2):

solved the issue with:

```
import curses
window = curses.initscr()
window.addstr(1, 0, "my text")
window.refresh()
curses.endwin()
```

Answer (score 0):

For simple applications you can use:

```
print('\n' * number_of_lines)
```

For more advanced there is [curses](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html) module in standard library.

Comment: that obviously works however I don't want to just clear the screen by writing new lines, all I want is the current screen to be updated. Exactly like how the "top" command works on linux, just updates the current screen without clearing the screen.